# How to convert PNG or JPEG to UIBezierPath in objective C

Tags: objective-c, image-processing, uibezierpath

This sample using UIBezierPath.

PNG or JPEG image possible to UIBezierPath ?

Sample Image Hearth :

[image]

Sample Bezier Path :

```
+ (UIBezierPath *)heartShape:(CGRect)originalFrame
{
    CGRect frame = [self maximumSquareFrameThatFits:originalFrame];

    UIBezierPath* bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [bezierPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.74182 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.04948 * CGRectGetHeight(frame))];
    [bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.49986 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.24129 * CGRectGetHeight(frame)) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.64732 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.05022 * CGRectGetHeight(frame)) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.55044 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.11201 * CGRectGetHeight(frame))];
    [bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.33067 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.06393 * CGRectGetHeight(frame)) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.46023 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.14682 * CGRectGetHeight(frame)) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.39785 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.08864 * CGRectGetHeight(frame))];
    [bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.25304 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.05011 * CGRectGetHeight(frame)) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.30516 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.05454 * CGRectGetHeight(frame)) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.27896 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.04999 * CGRectGetHeight(frame))];
    [bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.00841 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.36081 * CGRectGetHeight(frame)) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.12805 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.05067 * CGRectGetHeight(frame)) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.00977 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.15998 * CGRectGetHeight(frame))];
    [bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.29627 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.70379 * CGRectGetHeight(frame)) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.00709 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.55420 * CGRectGetHeight(frame)) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.18069 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.62648 * CGRectGetHeight(frame))];
    [bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.50061 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.92498 * CGRectGetHeight(frame)) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.40835 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.77876 * CGRectGetHeight(frame)) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.48812 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.88133 * CGRectGetHeight(frame))];
    [bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.70195 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.70407 * CGRectGetHeight(frame)) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.50990 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.88158 * CGRectGetHeight(frame)) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.59821 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.77912 * CGRectGetHeight(frame))];
    [bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.99177 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.35870 * CGRectGetHeight(frame)) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.81539 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.62200 * CGRectGetHeight(frame)) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.99308 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.55208 * CGRectGetHeight(frame))];
    [bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.74182 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.04948 * CGRectGetHeight(frame)) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.99040 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.15672 * CGRectGetHeight(frame)) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.86824 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.04848 * CGRectGetHeight(frame))];
    [bezierPath closePath];
    bezierPath.miterLimit = 4;

    return bezierPath;
}
```

Comment: Search for "UIView into UIImage"

Answer (score -3, accepted):

1. Create UIImage context.

   ```
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(width,height), NO, 1.0);
   ```
2. Draw some paths, shapes, etc..

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/HandlingImages/Images.html

3. Close context and get UIImage instance;

   ```
   UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
   ```
4. Get JPEG data:

`NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);`

Comment: The OP wants to convert an image to a bezier path, not convert some drawing to an image.

Comment: It doesn't answer the OP's question, the OP asks about vice versa